# HP Deskjet MFD printer

Tags: scanner

I have a HP Deskjet 2542 MFD printer.  I am looking to use the scanner, with either Simple Scan or Xscane, but I cannot get it to do so.  I am using Ubuntu 14.04 OS. In doing research, I discovered a package called: Synaptic Packaging Manager; and the person, who install the printer went to, HP Printing an Imaging, using 3.13.8 Many thanks, if you can help

Comment: Hi, welcome to Askubuntu! Please don't try to continue the conversation in private (by including your email). This is because, if you do this, the only person being helped is you. **We here at askubuntu try to help everyone who has the same problem**, that's why we keep everything in the open.

Answer (score 1):

Your printer is supported by hplip: http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/deskjet_aio/deskjet_2540_series.html

You can download hplip here: http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/downloads.html

## How to install hplip

1. Download the file to a convenient location (e.g., home directory or desktop, etc)
2. Open a console/terminal and cd to the location where the installer was downloaded. (e.g., cd ~/Desktop)
3. run the installer

   `sh hplip-3.15.2.run`